# svn repository creation

Tags: svn

I have installed SVN Tortoise and want to create a repository.
I followed the manual and typed "svnadmin ........" on the correct directory on command prompt.
It doesnt recognize the word svnadmin: 'svnadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command.........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tortoise does not install the command line tools. To create a new repository:

- create a directory using Explorer
- change into the directory
- right click on the empty directory pane
- choose "Create Repository Here" from the Tortoise menu

If you want the command line tools you can get them [here](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/).

Comment: Then you haven't installed Tortoise SVN properly.

Comment: I've just come across this problem too. The command line tools are now an optional component of the standard TortoiseSVN installer so just make sure you select them when you install.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the repository by just creating an empty folder, then open it and right-click and select TortoiseSVN->Create repository here.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your %PATH% variable accordingly. Although, I wonder why the installer didn't do this for you.
Make sure that TortoiseSVN has actually installed the svn tools, also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TortoiseSVN from the command line, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.methylblue.com/blog/using-tortoisesvn-from-the-command-line/). The bash script should be easily portable to Windows, too. You basically call "Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseProc.exe" with some parameters.

Though it seems you can't create a repository this way and only do basic tasks like commit/update.